# Android Studio Fails with: "File was deleted, but previous version not found in cache"

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a project on Android Studio which was working. But after I ran
`git pull` and then `git reset --hard` and tried to run it again, build failed with the message:

`File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@412e039a' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Build` -> `Clean Project` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Search for any instances of OpenJDK or java in task manager click and End Task
3. Run flutter clean in IDE

The Reason was Flutter Clean cant delete the build while the Application is still running in the Background process, u have to close it and run.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue. it occurs when you run> flutter clean command that actually did't clean all the files inside build directory of your project, and causes the issue.
So the simple solution is,  delete your build directory manually. If it alerts "File in Use" dialogue then simple do the following steps

1. open the run command with shortcut Window+R
2. type resmon.exe it will open the resource monitor
3. click on "CPU" tab
4. click on "Associated handles" and type build in search bar
5. right click on java.exe and end process
6. restart your IDEA and run your project the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to fix this issue is to run `flutter clean`.

You mentioned you are using android studio, go to your terminal inside android studio and then run the above mentioned command.

After the above command was executed then run your app again.

This simple solution worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio 3.6.2 for a Flutter project there is no 'Build -> Clean' unless you 'Open Android module in Android studio'. Then there is a 'Build -> Clean Project'.

An alternative as mentioned above is to open the terminal in the project where you may Debug your application and run 'flutter clean'.

For me the latter is better since I typically only open the Flutter android module when I want to build a release of my app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android module in Android studio
2. run success
3. execute ‘Build -> Clean’
4. close Android module in Android studio
5. run flutter project again